# rails 4 redirect routes to subdomain and change path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, subdomain, parameters

I want to create redirects for ~= 10 routes in my Rails 4 app:

- redirect to subdomain
- keep params even in POST/PUT (possible ?)
- change end of path
- keep locale
- keep the scheme

Example:

> http://example.com/fr/cloud/signup?format=json

to:

> http://services.example.com/fr/users/create?format=json

All my new routes with subdomains are already created and working.

A simple test, this is working:

```
get '/admin', to: redirect("http://admin.example.com", status: 301)
```

Now I want to build the new url with the scheme, keep params, locale...etc
I tried:

```
get '/app', to: redirect { |params, request| "#{request.protocol}apps.#{request.host}/#{I18n.locale.to_s}" }, status: 301
```

The locale is not working (tried also :locale or locale without success).
How to pass params ?

Another example with post:

```
post '/cloud/signup', to: redirect { |params, request| "#{request.protocol}services.#{request.host}/users/create" }, status: 301
```

How to transfer params ?
Thanks.